# When did politicians begin to refer to "the economy"?

Tags: economy

These days most politicians are preoccupied with the economy and economic growth.  Famously, Bill Clinton's campaign strategist James Carville coined the term "[the economy, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_the_economy,_stupid)" in 1992.  But conceptually, the very idea of an "economy" seems relatively modern.  The concept of [GDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product#History) (an objective measure of national economy) was first used in contemporary terms after 1944.

When did American and European politicians start referring to "the economy" as a thing which had to be prioritised?

Bonus question: What exactly did politicians refer to prior to the rise of the economy as a political concept?  How did they express what we would think of as economic concerns?  Were these even salient issues at the time?

Comment: Probably after the end of cold war. Before 20th century there isn't much of an economy. People spent almost 20th century killing or avoiding being killed by each other or in preparation of such.

Comment: @user3528438 "The German economy must be ready for war within 4 years" - [Adolf Hitler, 1936](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Year_Plan).

Comment: As a word, it's been used in the current sense [since the 1650's](https://www.etymonline.com/word/economy#etymonline_v_980).  Whether it's been in _common_ political usage, I don't know.

Comment: google's ngram viewer shows the writen term "the economy" started to ramp up during/right after WWII, although I don't know how to associate that with politicians